# How to set Home and End to Ctrl on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad New X1 Carbon. Since they put <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> at the position of <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd>, I want to map both of these two key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I've tried some method, but none of the following seems to work on my computer:

1. Key map setted by `xmodmap` will be reset after randomly;
2. I didn't find the required function in `setxkbmap`;
3. Gnome Tweak Tool doesn't contains such function;
4. I tried to change few lines of file `pc` and `us` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any suggestions about this problem? I'm not going to set a totally new layout and I'll not use the old layout anymore, it's OK to modify the current configure file in my computer.